# Como colocar um json retornado de uma API dentro de um select?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

Estou tentando fazer o formulário de pagamento por cartão de crédito, usando a API do pagar.me. Gostaria de calcular as parcelas via API e retorná-las dentro de um . Eu consigo retornar o json e retorná-lo no console.log. Mas não sei como colocá-lo dentro do .

HTML:

```
<form id="payment_form" action="pay_creditcard_pagarme.php" method="POST">
<div id="form">
    Número do cartão: <input type="text" id="card_number" maxlength="16" />
    <br />

    Nome (como escrito no cartão): <input type="text" id="card_holder_name" />
    <br />

    Mês de expiração: <input type="text" id="card_expiration_month" />
    <br />

    Ano de expiração: <input type="text" id="card_expiration_year" />
    <br />

    Código de segurança: <input type="text" id="card_cvv" />
    <br />

    <select name="installment_quantity" id="select-installments">
        <option selected>1</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
</div>

    <input type="submit" value="Pagar">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#card_number").keyup(function(){
        var cardNumber = $("input[id='card_number']").val();

        //if creditcard number is finished, get installments
        if(cardNumber.length != 16){
            return;
        }

        pagarme.client.connect({ api_key: 'my_api_key' })
          .then(client => client.transactions.calculateInstallmentsAmount({
            id: 1234,
            max_installments: 3,
            free_installments: 2,
            interest_rate: 2,
            amount: 1000
          }))
          .then(installments => {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(installments));

            // Acredito que a partir deste ponto algo está errado.
            inst = installments;
            $("#select-installments").html("");
            for(var installment in inst.length){
                $("#select-installments").append("<option value='" + inst.installment + "'>" + inst.installment + " x R$ " + inst.installment_amount + " - " + (inst.installment <= 3? "Sem" : "Com")  + " Juros</option>");
            }

            });


    });
```

Resultado do console.log:

```
{"installments":{"1": 
{"installment":1,"amount":1000,"installment_amount":1000},"2": 
{"installment":2,"amount":1000,"installment_amount":500},"3": 
{"installment":3,"amount":1060,"installment_amount":353}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso pegar os objetos dentro de `installments` do retorno com o mesmo nome. Ficaria:

```
let inst = installments.installments;
```

O primeiro `installments` é o que vem do retorno da função, o segundo é um objeto dentro do retorno, onde existem outros objetos de onde você quer pegar as informações.

No `for` você não irá usar `.length` porque não é uma array, mas sim uma coleção de objetos, e nesse tipo de `for` não precisa saber o tamanho do que você vai iterar.

Em vez de usar `$("#select-installments").html("");` para esvaziar o select, use um método próprio pra isso, `.empty()`: `$("#select-installments").empty();`

E em vez de `<=3`, deveria ser `<3` (menor que 3), se não a opção "com juros" irá ficar "sem juros".

Seu código ficaria assim, onde simulei o retorno da função com uma variável `installments` simples:

```js
installments = {"installments":{"1": 
{"installment":1,"amount":1000,"installment_amount":1000},"2": 
{"installment":2,"amount":1000,"installment_amount":500},"3": 
{"installment":3,"amount":1060,"installment_amount":353}}}

// copie somente daqui pra baixo
let inst = installments.installments;
$("#select-installments").empty();
for(let i in inst){
   $("#select-installments").append("<option value='" + inst[i].installment + "'>" + inst[i].installment + " x R$ " + inst[i].installment_amount + " - " + (inst[i].installment < 3? "Sem" : "Com")  + " Juros</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="installment_quantity" id="select-installments">
   <option selected>1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Tente este código:

```js
//data
var d = {"installments":
    {"1": {"installment":1,"amount":1000,"installment_amount":1000},
    "2": {"installment":2,"amount":1000,"installment_amount":500},
    "3": {"installment":3,"amount":1060,"installment_amount":353}}}

    console.log(d.installments); //obtém tudo
    console.log(d.installments[1].installment); //primeiro registro.
    console.log(d.installments[1].amount); //primeiro registro.
    console.log(d.installments[1].installment_amount); //primeiro registro.


    console.log(d.installments[2]); //segundo registro.
    //etc.

    let data = d.installments;
    for(let index in data){
    
    //Exemplo para inserir no HTML

      $("#select-installments").append("<option value='" + data[index].amount+ "'>" + data[index].amount+ " x R$ " + data[index].amount + " - " + (data[index].amount <= 3? "Sem" : "Com")  + " Juros</option>");
      
    console.log(data[index].installment);
    console.log(data[index].amount);
    console.log(data[index].installment_amount);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="installment_quantity" id="select-installments">
    <option selected>1</option>
</select>
```